# Why can't I load some libraries in RASA

Tags: rasa-nlu

```
from rasa_nlu.training_data import load_data
from rasa_nlu.model import Trainer
from rasa_nlu import config

 // can't find these modules
from rasa_nlu.converters import load_data
from rasa_nlu.config import RasaNLUConfig
```

I installed the rasa_starter tutorial with all requirements, then tried to import dependencies as above. Some imports are successful, some failed, as seen from the 2 examples above.

Comment: which starter tutorial? Can you share the link?

Answer (score 0):

I guess some import changed between the different rasa versions.
Please consider updating to the stable Rasa version, e.g. by doing `pip install rasa`